# Adding the first ten odd numbers - incorrect output

Tags: java, loops, for-loop

I'm writing a program that adds the first ten odd numbers, and gets the sum at the end.

Here is my code so far. My code reads the odd number in a list of 10 numbers. I want my code to be able to read 10 odd numbers even if there are more than 10 numbers entered. I know the problem is `i < 10`, which makes the program stop after the 10th number.

```
import java.util.Scanner;
```

public class question14 
{

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);

    int odd,sum=0;
    System.out.println("enter numbers");

    int i = 0;
            while(i < 10) {
                odd = keyboard.nextInt();
                if (odd % 2 != 0) {
                    sum = sum + odd;
                    i++;
                }
            }
            System.out.println("The sum of first 10 odd numbers is " + sum);

}
```

}

Comment: and your console output?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Wrap it in a while loop instead.

While oddnumbers < 10 ask for a new number.

```
int i = 0
while(i < 10) {
    odd = keyboard.nextInt();
    if (odd % 2 != 0) {
        sum = sum + odd;
        i++;
    }
}
System.out.println("The sum of first 10 odd numbers is " + sum);
```

EDIT:FULL CODE

import java.util.Scanner;

/*
 * To change this template, choose Tools | Templates
 * and open the template in the editor.
 */

/**
 *
 * @author stevengreen22
 */
public class NewMain {

```
/**
 * @param args the command line arguments
 */
public static void main(String[] args) {
    // TODO code application logic here 
    Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);

    int i = 0; 
    int sum = 0;
    int input;
    int inputCount = 0;

    while (i < 10){
        //Having this inside the while loop prompts the user every time.  
        System.out.println("New number?");
        input = scan.nextInt();
        inputCount++;

        if(input % 2 == 1){
            sum += input;
            i++;
        }
    }

    System.out.println("sum: "+sum);
    System.out.println("Number of odds:" + i);
    System.out.println("Numbe of inputs: " +inputCount);
    System.out.println("Average cos I miss typing sout tab:" + (inputCount/sum));
}
```

}

Comment: Sorry Brian. Using phone. Could you edit for me please? If you don't min that is.

Comment: Tried this but it doesn't do anything after entering numbers

Comment: @treasure - you will need ot modify it somewhat by adding in the relevant scanner lines etc.  I think someone else posted the full code  that you'd need but from what I wrote it should be relatively easy to piece it together yourself.  What is your output?

Comment: output is nothing. IT doesn't do anything after i enter the numbers.

Comment: paste what you've tried so far and I'll help. I'm not goign to do all your homework for you :)

Comment: Updated the code
It's the same thing except that i used a while loop

Comment: Add your console output too - I just tested and it worked fine : run:
New number?
12
New number?
2
New number?
3
New number?
1
New number?
2
New number?
3
New number?
1
New number?
1
New number?
1
New number?
1
New number?
1
New number?
3
New number?
4
New number?
3
sum: 18
Number of odds:10
Numbe of inputs: 14

Comment: it works fine, it's your understanding of it and the console input that needs work :)  Are you using netbeans?  You're not prompting the user to enter another number so you have to press enter and then a number and then enter again etc, you can see the values / variables update when debugging.  I've updated mine so you can see it more clerly but there's nothign at all wrong with the code

Comment: ahh works i was doing some thing stupid. Thanks for your help guys

Answer (score 1):

The principle thing is that you don't know how many numbers the user is going to enter into the program, so you want to use a `while` loop instead of a `for` loop.

One chooses a `for` loop when they know how many elements they want to iterate over; one chooses a `while` loop when they don't know how many elements they'll need to iterate over.

You'll need to define another variable called `counter` outside of the loop, and use this as your loop variable constraint.

```
while(counter < 10) {
    // loop
}
```

You'll also need to update `counter` whenever you encounter an odd value.

Comment: Explained much better than me:)

Comment: Yes makes more sense to use a while loop.

Answer (score 0):

This should work

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);

    int odd,sum=0;
    System.out.println("enter numbers");

    int i=0;
    while (i<10){
        odd=keyboard.nextInt();
        if (odd%2!=0){
            sum=sum+odd;
            i++;
        }  
    }
    System.out.println("The sum of first 10 odd numbers is "+sum);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Just replace your for loop with a while loop and track the number of odd numbers in an integer:

```
int oddNumberCount = 0;
int inputNumber;
while(oddNumberCount<10)
{
inputNumber = keyboard.nextInt();
if(inputNumber%2!=0)
{
      sum = sum+inputNumber;
      oddNumberCount++;
}
}
```